# Infinite recursion in drools after version change from v7.20 to v7.21

Tags: drools

**When there is a version change in drools-compiler from `7.20.0.Final` to `7.21.0.Final` some rules are looping recursively.**

**Code in github:**

[The working version](https://github.com/padippist/DroolsIssueReporting/tree/issue_v_7.20)

[The recursively looping version](https://github.com/padippist/DroolsIssueReporting/tree/issue_v_7.21)

[The change between working and looping version](https://github.com/padippist/DroolsIssueReporting/compare/issue_v_7.20...issue_v_7.21)

**More details**

When I fire a rule whose `then` part modifies a fact that is already checked in the `when` part:

```
rule "rule 1.1"
  when
    $sampleDomain: SampleDomain(instanceVariable2 == "Value of instance variable")
  then
    System.out.println("Rule 1.1 fired");
    modify($sampleDomain){
            setInstanceVariable1(3)
    }
end
```

it doesn't loop recursively.

But when I call another rule which call a static function from another class:

```
rule "rule 1.2"
  when
    $sampleDomain: SampleDomain(CoreUtils.anotherFunction())
  then
    System.out.println("Rule 1.2 fired");
    modify($sampleDomain){
            setInstanceVariable1(3)
    }
end
```

it loops recursively.

The class with static function is

```
import com.drool_issue.domain.SampleDomain;

public class CoreUtils {

    public static boolean anotherFunction() {
        System.out.println("anotherFunction() inside CoreUtils");
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean anotherFunction(SampleDomain sampleDomain) {
        System.out.println("anotherFunction(SampleDomain sampleDomain) inside CoreUtils");
        return true;
    }

}
```

My domain file is:

```
public class SampleDomain {
    private int instanceVariable1;
    private String instanceVariable2;
    private int instanceVariable3;


    public int getInstanceVariable1() {
        return instanceVariable1;
    }
    public void setInstanceVariable1(int instanceVariable1) {
        this.instanceVariable1 = instanceVariable1;
    }
    public String getInstanceVariable2() {
        return instanceVariable2;
    }
    public void setInstanceVariable2(String instanceVariable2) {
        this.instanceVariable2 = instanceVariable2;
    }
    public int getInstanceVariable3() {
        return instanceVariable3;
    }
    public void setInstanceVariable3(int instanceVariable3) {
        this.instanceVariable3 = instanceVariable3;
    }



}
```

This is only caused after version change from `7.20.0.Final` to `7.21.0.Final`.  Any guess on what the problem might be?

When I further looked into the problem I saw this too.

When we add two functions into the `SampleDomain` class ie

```
    public boolean anotherFunction() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean anotherFunction(SampleDomain sampleDomain) {
        return true;
    }
```

and use this in the rule like:

```
rule "rule 1.4"
  when
    $sampleDomain: SampleDomain(anotherFunction())
  then
    System.out.println("Rule 1.4 fired");
    modify($sampleDomain){
            setInstanceVariable1(3)
    }
end
```

and

```
rule "rule 1.5"
  when
    $sampleDomain: SampleDomain(anotherFunction($sampleDomain))
  then
    System.out.println("Rule 1.5 fired");
    modify($sampleDomain){
            setInstanceVariable3(4)
    }
end
```

these also loops recursively.

**Code in github:**

[The recursive looping when using non static methods](https://github.com/padippist/DroolsIssueReporting/tree/issue_v_7.20_non_static_methodes)

[The change between working and above version](https://github.com/padippist/DroolsIssueReporting/compare/issue_v_7.20...issue_v_7.20_non_static_methodes)

Also when any of the static method is made non static then method from the domain class is called even though the static method is specified in the rule.

**Code portions to be noted here are:**

[Rule where static method is called.](https://github.com/padippist/DroolsIssueReporting/blob/bde2804b250babf11cf5d3cf48640d9e6c88f5b3/src/main/resources/rules/rule1.drl#L21)

[Another rule which also call the static method.](https://github.com/padippist/DroolsIssueReporting/blob/bde2804b250babf11cf5d3cf48640d9e6c88f5b3/src/main/resources/rules/rule1.drl#L32)

[The static access modifier removed from the functions which where previously static.](https://github.com/padippist/DroolsIssueReporting/compare/issue_v_7.20...issue_v_7.21_weird_behaviors#diff-4e0f238b1184e2267cb5663b9afeaa6fL7)

**Code in github:**

[Weird behaviour when removing static modifier for the functions.](https://github.com/padippist/DroolsIssueReporting/tree/issue_v_7.21_weird_behaviors)

[The change between working and above version](https://github.com/padippist/DroolsIssueReporting/compare/issue_v_7.20...issue_v_7.21_weird_behaviors)

All this are caused in versions after `7.20.0.Final`, ie `7.21.0.Final`, `7.22.0.Final` and `7.23.0.Final`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property reactivity based filtering cannot  be applied to external  function  since we don't know what  the external function (static method) does internally.

To elaborate this:
Let us start with Property reactivity; whenever we use the  modify or update keywords in the consequence of a rule, we're notify the engine that rules that filter similar object types should re-evaluate the object again. This re-evaluation, by default, occurs on the whole object.  That is as long as one property of the object  changes, the rules will consider it as a new object to match.  This could lead to some issues when we don't wish to have a rule re-evaluated for some changes. The loop-control mechanisms, such as no-loop and lock-on-active, could be helpful in these situations. However, if we want the rule to control changes on some  properties only, we need to write very complex conditions. Also, if the model changes in the future for a large rule base, you may have to modify a lot of rules to avoid undesired rule re-executions.  Fortunately, Drools provides a feature that allows the engine to work around this problem. It allows the rule writers to define the attributes of a bean that should be monitored if they're updated in the working memory. This feature can be defined in the data  model (both Java classes or declared types) that are used in the rules and it is called property-reactive beans.

To use this feature, we first need to mark the types that we will use in the rules with the Property Reactive annotation. This annotation allows the engine know that whenever an object of this type is added to the working memory, special filtering on  its changes needs to apply.  This  annotation can  be added to a Java class (at class level) or declared type (right after the first line, defining the type name), as follows,
In Java  class:

```
@PropertyReactive public class Customer {     ... }
```

In declared  type:

```
    declare PropertyReactiveOrder        
        @propertyReactive
        discount: Discount
        totalItems: Integer
        total: Double    
    end
```

We can also make all the types property reactive by adding `PropertySpecificOption.ALWAYS` to builder option.

Note: Property reactive beans changes would be notified to the rule engine only using the modify keyword.  The update keyword won't be able to tell the difference between the attributes of the bean that are being changed.

Property reactivity has been introduced in Drools 5.4 but since using this feature is considered a good practice both under correctness and performance points of view, it has been enabled by default in Drools 7.0.

Now once again to our problem, although with property  reactivity things have drastically changed and it has been acting like a Fine grained property change listener that allows Drools to understand a little bit more  about what is going on inside the RHS of our rules, or at least inside the modify() operation.  The functions are still a black box for it, thus creating this problem.